# How to add textField in UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I want to realize a function about changing password. It requires users to input their previous password in an alert dialog.

I want to click the button "Confirm the modification" then jump to the other view controller for changing password. I have written some code, but I don't know how to write in the next moment.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Change password" message:@"Please input your previous password" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"please input your previous password";
    textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
}];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handlers:nil];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Confirm the modification" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:*(UIAlertAction *alertAction) {
    if (condition) {
        statements
    }
}];

[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/KiritVaghela/UIAlertController

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can add multiple textfields to alert controller and access them with the alert controller's `textFields` property

If the new password is an empty string, present the alert again. Or another way would be to disable the "Confirm" button, enabling it only when text field has text.

```
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"confirm the modification" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    UITextField *password = alertController.textFields.firstObject;
    if (![password.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

        //change password

    }
    else{
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}];
```

Comment: the key is how to get the textfield in alertcontroller.So I think this line is very important !
UITextField *password = alertController.textFields.firstObject;
When I know this code , I can write the next code.

Comment: How to disable Confirm button

Comment: Referencing `alertController` within the action's block leads to a retain cycle. You should only refer to it via weak reference: `__weak typeof(alertController) weakAlert = alertController;` ... `UIAlertAction *...` `...password = weakAlert.textFields.firstObject;`

Answer (score 105):

You will get all added textfields from alert controller by its `textFields` readonly property, you can use it to get its text.
Like

**Swift 4:**

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addTextField { textField in
    textField.placeholder = "Password"
    textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
}
let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { [weak alertController] _ in
    guard let alertController = alertController, let textField = alertController.textFields?.first else { return }
    print("Current password \(String(describing: textField.text))")
    //compare the current password and do action here
}
alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Note:** textField.text is optional, unwrap it before using

**Objective-C:**

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"Current password";
    textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
}];
UIAlertAction *confirmAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    NSLog(@"Current password %@", [[alertController textFields][0] text]);
    //compare the current password and do action here

}];
[alertController addAction:confirmAction];
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    NSLog(@"Canelled");
}];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

By `[[alertController textFields][0] text]` this line, it will take first textfield added to the alerController and get its text.

Comment: I want to know what does this code " [alertController textFields] [0] text" mean?

Comment: @Juice007 it means that you are getting the first textfield of the alertcontroller and gettings its text, pretty simple

Comment: you SHOULD use  `[weak alertController]` to avoid a retain cycle.

Answer (score 15):

Here is an updated answer for Swift 4.0 that creates the desired kind of textfield:

```
// Create a standard UIAlertController
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Entry", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

// Add a textField to your controller, with a placeholder value & secure entry enabled
alertController.addTextField { textField in
    textField.placeholder = "Enter password"
    textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    textField.textAlignment = .center
}

// A cancel action
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
    print("Canelled")
}

// This action handles your confirmation action
let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in
    print("Current password value: \(alertController.textFields?.first?.text ?? "None")")
}

// Add the actions, the order here does not matter
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
alertController.addAction(confirmAction)

// Present to user
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And how it looks when first presented:
[image]

And while accepting text:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I found this very useful however it adds a UITextField to the UIViewController as well as allowing it to be used in the UIAlertController. Is there a way to stop this or to remove it after you click Cancel / OK?

Comment: Thanks, quick solution

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.1

[image]

```
@objc func promptAddDialog() {
    let ac = UIAlertController.init(title: "Enter answer", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addTextField{ textField in
        textField.placeholder = "Answer"
        textField.textAlignment = .center
    }
    
    let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) {
    [weak self, weak ac] _ in
    guard let answer = ac?.textFields?[0].text else { return }
    self?.submit(answer)
    }
    ac.addAction(submitAction)
    present(ac, animated: true)
}
```