# AlertController TextField Input to Change Text in Label

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm wanting to change my label "teamNameLabel" whenever a user inputs text into my textfield from AlertController and hit's the ENTER button.

I'm really close. I just need the text once entered to display as my label when the hit the ENTER button.

ALSO: Is there anyway to make the text entered into my textfield CAPITALS ONLY? (eg. User has to enter "TEAM NAME" and not "team name")

See code and images below:

```
@IBAction func editTeamNameButton() {

    let message = "Please Enter Below"
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "ENTER TEAM NAME", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ENTER", style: .default, handler: nil)


    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)


    alert.addAction(action)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.preferredAction = action


    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Eg. TEAM NAME"



    })

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

[Click Here To View Screenshot Of My AlertController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOEOi.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504317/how-to-add-textfield-in-uialertcontroller  It's the `let textField = alertController.textFields?.first` part that allow to retrieve the content of the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add handler for your `UIAlertAction` and in this handler you can check if first `UITextField` in `alert`'s `textFields` exists, and if exists, you can assign `text` property of your label as `text` property of this `textField`

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ENTER", style: .default) { _ in
    if let textField = alert.textFields?[0] {
        self.teamNameLabel.text = textField.text!
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I make the input text by the user CAPITALS Only?

Comment: @J.Kearney https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092182/uppercase-characters-in-uitextfield